# Git rebase from one parent commit on top of a new parent commit (that doesn't have the old parent commit as one of its parents)

Tags: git, gerrit

*EDIT: We are using Gerrit. Local changes are transferred to Gerrit, where they undergo review and are then merged (by Gerrit) to the remote master branch.*

A number of times now I have run into a specific rebase problem that exceeds my limited understanding of how Git functions. Imagine the following scenario (while all this is happening, no other activity takes place on `origin/master`):

You create a new commit `A` that is based directly on what is currently on `origin/master`. Before `A` has even been merged to `origin/master`, you already create a new commit `B` that is based directly on commit `A`.

Now while commit `A` is undergoing review, it is decided that commit `A` should be split up into two separate commits. So you create a new commit `A0` that is based directly on `origin/master` and move part of the changes in `A` into the newly created `A0`. Now `A0` is merged, becoming the new `origin/master`. Next the original `A` (which is now slimmer because it no longer contains the stuff that was moved to `A0`) is rebased on top of `A0` (i.e. on top of `origin/master`) and then merged to `origin/master`. So far so good.

Next (to prepare for merging `B` to `origin/master`) you try to rebase `B` on top of `origin/master`. And this is where it all goes horribly wrong (for me, anyway).

When I run the steps (in a Git bash) I normally do to rebase a change:

- git fetch --prune
- git rebase origin/master

Git complains that there is one conflict that must be resolved manually. In my case, this is a changelog.txt file. In `B`'s original history, this changelog.txt file contained one combined change log entry for the formerly combined `A0` and `A` change. In the new parent `B` is being rebased on top of this combined change log entry has now been split into 2 separate change log entries, and apparently that is not something that Git can resolve automatically.

I'm fine with that. Resolving that myself shouldn't be particularly hard, so I start my graphical merge tool. HOWEVER, while the merge tool lets me choose between the old combined change log entry on one side and the new separate change log entries on the other side, I notice that the new change log entry supplied by `B` itself is missing completely (regardless of which choice I make)!! I don't understand why Git forgets about this part. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot commit or merge to `origin/master` so what are we really talking about? Did you mean `master` throughout the question?

Comment: it seems like the conflict that you are solving is the conflict when rebasing A on A0, probably you aren't solving the conflict for commit B (yet).

Comment: @matt Sorry if my terminology is a bit wonky. I guess I should have mentioned that we use Gerrit and thus have a remote master repository. My local changes are "transferred" to Gerrit, where they undergo review and are then "merged" onto the remote master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that B is standing on top of the original A.... you could do this:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master B~1 B
```

This way you are only moving the very only revision that is B-related and not anything coming from A. If there is more than one revision related to B, just adjust the number of revisions on the second-to-last argument (3 revisions? B~3).

Comment: Aye, that works! :) Strangely, git still complains about a conflict that must be resolved automatically, but when I actually run the graphical merge tool, it shows that it managed to resolve the conflicts itself without my intervention. But that's not really an issue, so thanks! :)

Comment: Still, I find it a bit disappointing that git needs hand-holding to do this correctly. Why can't git rebase detect this automatically without me having to provide special options? I'm more of a ClearCase guy, and in ClearCase scenarios like the one I described worked just fine without the user having to perform any special options voodoo magic. :-\

Comment: Hmm.... I don't think git is failing.... you did something behind its back (rewrote A's history) and you set up B on top of the _original_ A so....

Comment: Ok, then I suppose the culprit is that I still haven't really understood how git works. I probably still live in my old ClearCase world too much.

Comment: I don't know ClearCase so can't really tell how you could think about it... but here's a tip that does help a lot understand why git behaves like it does sometimes: **branches are pointers to revisions**, nothing else. So... You had A originally pointing to a revision, B was started from there (and also pointed to that same revision)... then you committed stuff on B (and moved the pointer to those revisions)... and then you decided to rewrite the history of A... and therefore you moved that pointer.... but for B, it was still at the same spot is was before....

Comment: ... and it didn't notice that A moved.... nor does it care... but you do care, right? Well, that's it :-)